# How should we tag the editions of Rolemaster?

Tags: discussion, tags

Here is some good info on the [various editions throughout it's history](http://www.icewebring.com/ice-products/).  At the very least it might be helpful to get tags to distinguish between the Rolemaster Standard System or RMSS and Rolemaster Fantasy Roleplaying or RMFRP, since these were the most popular versions.

As of right now, the Editions are:

- Rolemaster First Edition or RM1
- Rolemaster Second Edition or RM2
- Rolemaster Standard System or RMSS
- Rolemaster Fantasy Roleplaying or RMFRP
- Rolemaster Classic or RMC (an update of RM2)
- Rolemaster Express or RMX (a rules lite version of RMC)
- Unified Rolemaster

I would be happy to write up the tag info as needed.

Comment: Since getting a tag is as easy as writing it during a post edit, these things don't need to be requested on Meta. However, figuring out a new collection of tags that work together (and whether they're all/each even needed) is something Meta's good for, so I've tweaked the question to focus on starting that discussion. Does it look good?

Comment: Yes - looks good.  Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 3):

In general, we don't need to plan tags.

Tagging here is an emergent folksonomy.  Tags are created because someone's asking questions about something, and for no other reason.

We go from a generic tag down to version tags if and when it matters.  For many games it doesn't. For Call of Cthulhu, we just have a [call-of-cthulhu] tag because a) the differences between the versions are not all that much and b) the play community for those games doesn't care all that much.

Currently we have a [rolemaster] tag.  We don't need further breakdown of the tag unless people are asking questions that are version dependent and really need those tags.  And per [What are the differences between the first and second editions of Rolemaster?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3482/what-are-the-differences-between-the-first-and-second-editions-of-rolemaster) the versions don't seem to be that different to merit it.

In general, having to break down tagging based on version is a necessary evil to be avoided unless it really is necessary because it hinders people from following/participating across the whole larger scope of the game - for D&D that's the right thing to do, but in very few other cases.

Comment: RMSS & RMFRP are different enough.  I have had to ask for clarification on certain questions.  It just that RM questions in general don't come up that often.

Comment: I think the principle in this answer holds — we create tags as needed — but I think the state of RM questions does mean that we'd benefit from seeing one or two new tags where the plain [rolemaster] tag is insufficiently informative. I've noticed the confusion come up a handful of times. (I don't think we need new tags for *all* the many editions.)

Comment: OK then, let's propose what we do specifically want to do.

Comment: I have started with the RMSS tag on the most recent question where I found it relevant.  When an RMFRP question pops up, I can add that tag then.